# updating fields via SharePoint Form and via List item event receiver

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am confused and cannot seem to find the right answer to this problem:

When I use the ItemUpdating method in the event receiver to update the field title as show in the code below it works, but other fields which I have changed via the "Edit Form" do not change. they remain as they are.

```
public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    SPListitem item = properties.ListItem;
    item["Title"] = "title has been changed";
    item.Update();
}
```

if I put the above code in `ItemUpdated` it does not work, but the changes done via UI (edit form) take effect.

can anyone help me solve this problem?

thank you

### Editing

Let me put it simply like this:

can anyone tell me how can I update one or multiple fields via Event Receiver and the other field(s) via the Edit Form of a list?

I hope this is clearer.

Comment: In your paragraph before the code sample, you say the code sample works in `ItemUpdating`. Then after the code sample, you say it *doesn't* work in `ItemUpdating.` Which is it?

Comment: sorry but after the code I am using the word ItemUpdated and not ItemUpdating. Pls reader it again.

Comment: Sorry about that. Can you post sample code for 1 or 2 other fields you're trying to set? I suspect maybe you're not using the correct field names.

Answer (score 0):

It is always best to use ItemUpdated in the event receiver to update a field in the list.
and also you must note that updating the field in the event receiver using

item.Update();

might cause some problems when you start workflow. You can use the following 
ways to update multiple field.

```
               base.EventFiringEnabled = false;
               try
               {
                   item.SystemUpdate(false);
               }
               finally
               {
                   base.EventFiringEnabled = true;
               }
               break;
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the ItemUpdating event, check the `AfterProperties` property of the `properties` parameter. It is a dictionary containing all the new values that the item will have. It contains raw values, though, all of them as strings, before being processed into the actual values you'll see when you fetch the item properties.

When you execute your code in the `ItemUpdating` event, what happens is this:

- User clicks save;
- `ItemUpdating` is fired and executes up to your call to `Update()`.
- At this point, your call to `Update()` fires another `ItemUpdating` event to the item. In the context it runs, no fields have changed other than `Title`.
- Control returns to the method you overrode. The changes that were to be persisted to the item don't apply anymore.

And that's why you lose the changes made by the user.

When you use `ItemUpdated` instead, the changes made by the user are persisted because they are saved **before** you do anything. Then you call that `Update()` inside an `ItemUpdated` event. That one is either throwing a **stack overflow** exception silently or doing something else completely crazy, because you've created an **infinite recursion loop** there - and that's why you don't see it changing the title.

If you want to add extra changes to an item being saved by the UI, modify the `AfterProperties` property of `properties` instead of changing them directly in the item.